# Is it correct to say "postpone a partially done task"

Tags: word-usage, phrase-request

We can definitelly say "to postpone a task" if the task hasn't been started yet. 
Could you please explain whether it is correct to say "to postpone a task" if there is already some progress on the task (i.e. the task is partially done)?

If not, than what would be the appropriate phrase?

Comment: No, you can't really *postpone* something that's already in progress. You could feasibly *postpone **the target completion date***, though. Or *put the project **on hold*** if you're not even going to bother revising that target date for the time being.

Comment: Let's say one gets assigned to another task with a higher priority. They probably need to stop working on the current task (which is partially done). What is the correct word to describe the state of the current task? Is "Deferred" appropriate?

Comment: *Deferred, delayed, suspended, deprioritised, put on the back burner,...* There are [many different terms](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/put_on_the_back_burner.html) that might suit the exact "subsense" you want. In practice, the ***doing*** of the task (actually *working* on it) would be near-synonymous with the anticipated ***completion*** of it. But *some* verbs would more strongly imply not doing ***any*** work on a task for which the target completion date has been put back (or abandoned), whereas some others would imply just ***not working on it so much*** as before.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Thank you!